# push_back/emplace_back a shallow copy of an object into another vector

Tags: python, c++, vector

Say I have the following code

```
class Car {
    public:
        string color;
        string name;
        Car(string c, string n): color(c), name(n){}            
}

int main() {
    vector<Car> collection1;
    vector<Car> collection2;
    collection1.emplace_back("black", "Ford");
    collection1.emplace_back("white", "BMW");
    collection1.emplace_back("yellow", "Audi");

    //Question comes here
    collection2.push_back(collection1[0]);

}
```

Now I believe this does a deep copy of `collection1[0]`.
I have tried using `collection2.emplace_back(move(collection1[0]))`, but then the data fields of `collection1[0]` would be gone. I just want this "black Ford" to exist in both vectors, and changes made to this particular object, through either vector, would be reflected on both vectors.

I am guessing that for a vector of real objects, the elements of this vector take actual memory. So an element of `collection1` must be independent on any element of `collection2`. I think the easiest way is to let `collection1` and `collection2` to be vectors of pointers and point to the same vector of `Car`. But is there any possible means to make the above code work, without using vector of pointers. I ultimately want to return both of these collections back to the previous function, so making vectors of pointers is meaningless.

In short, I want to simulate the `List.append()` method in python.

```
collection1 = [Car("black", "Ford"),Car("white", "BMW"),Car("yellow", "Audi")]
collection2 = []
collection2.append(collection1[0])
collection2[0].color = "blue" // This affects collection1 as well
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>>`, then you get what you want.

Comment: In Python you deal with pointers all the time, they are just not called pointers in Python-speak. So in order to emulate Python you just need is to stop calling pointers pointers, and squint hard enough so that `->` looks like `.`. (Python pointers are "smart" (garbage-collected) and you need to use smart pointers in C++ too, but this is a minor detail).

Comment: @n.m. So you suggest I still do "let collection1 and collection2 to be vectors of pointers and point to the same vector of Car", and then make this "vector of Car" static so that i could access it after returning to the previous function?

Comment: No, you have vectors of shared_ptr and nothing static, just like the other comment suggests. Your objects are allocated on the heap.

Comment: There's really o such thing as "shallow" and "deep" copies in C++. There are copies, doing whatever the copy constructor(s) of a class does. It seems you need to store a different type (i.e. a pointer or `reference_wrapper`.)

Comment: @Mine that should be an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++ languages, standard collections actually contain the object while in other languages like Python or Java, they actually contain *references* (or pointers) to objects that are stored elsewhere. But as C++ does not include garbage collection, the lifetime of the object must be explicitly managed *elsewhere*.

The consequence of that design is that, to allow the same object to be used in two different collections, you **must** use collections of pointers or references (beware, C++ does not directly allow collections of references; however, `std::ref` was created for that).

Depending on your use case, you could either use raw pointers (if the lifetime of the actual objects is already managed), or use smart pointers (here, `std::shared_ptr`) that internally manage a reference count to ensure that the object is automatically destroyed when the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed. This is not far from Python's references to objects, provided you are aware that the destruction of the last `shared_ptr` will actually destroy the object(*). Said differently, do not keep any other pointers or references to it if you do not want it to become dangling.

Alternatively, if the collections are not symmetric—that is, if one will actually contain all the objects, while the other will only contain references to objects from the former one—*references* will be your best bet, and the second collection could be a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Car>>`.

---

Addition per MvG comment.

There is a possibly annoying difference between Python objects and C++ shared_ptr. Python has a full garbage collector that is clever enough to detect circular references and destroys the cycle as soon as there are no *external* references. Example:

```
>>> b = ['x']
>>> a = ['y']
>>> b.append(a)
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
['y', ['x', [...]]]
>>> b
['x', ['y', [...]]]
```

a contains a ref to b which contains a ref to a...

If a is deleted (or goes out of scope) b will still contain the full chain

```
>>> del a
>>> b
['x', ['y', [...]]]
```

but if both a and b are delete (or go out of scope), the gc will detect that there is no more external ref and will destroy everything.

Unfortunately, if you manage to build a cycle of C++ objects using `std::shared_ptr` as it only uses local ref counting, each object will have a ref to the other and they will never be deleted even when they will go out of scope which will lead to a memory leak. An example of that:

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
};

a = make_shared<Node>();  // ref count 1
b = make_shared<Node>();
a.next = std::shared_ptr<Node>(b);
b.next = std::shared_ptr<Node>(a); // ref count 2!
```

Hell has come here: even when a and b will both go out of scope, the ref count will still be one and the shared pointers will never delete their objects, what should have normally happend without the circular reference. The programmer must explicitely deals with that and break the cycle (and forbid it to happen). For example `b.next = make_shared<Node>();` before b goes out of scope would be enough.

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that `shared_ptr` doesn't detect cycles, contrary to Python references.

Comment: @MvG can you elaborate on that, please? (I'm not too familiar with python).

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned you don't like pointers, you can use references, but vectors can't store references (because they aren't copyable and assignable). However `std::reference_wrapper` wraps a reference in copyable and assignable object.

> `std::reference_wrapper` is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like `std::vector`) which cannot normally hold references.
>
> <sub>source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper</sub>

```
vector<Car> collection1;
collection1.emplace_back("black", "Ford");
collection1.emplace_back("white", "BMW");
collection1.emplace_back("yellow", "Audi");

vector<std::reference_wrapper<Car>> collection2{collection1.begin(),
                                                collection1.end()};
```

Using this way, `collection2` refers to the same objects as `collection1` does. For example:

```
collection1[0].name = "frogatto!";
std::cout << collection2[0].get().name;
// prints 'frogatto!'
```

**Important:**

Note that using this way is discouraged since you *must* have another entity that manages insertion and removal to/from `collection1` and takes appropriate actions on `collection2`. @[Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta)'s answer is better than mine. Use `std::shared_ptr`. Try to love and embrace pointers :)

Comment: This is poor style and bad code. Once `collection1` is altered, `collection2` will contain dangling references. This is a serious problem that should be avoided at the root of the design.

Comment: @Walter You're right, but I am not the _designer_ of OP's project. I just assumed that insertion and deletion of `collection1` is synced and managed by another entity.

Comment: @Walter Additionally I personally in such cases would prefer `std::shared_ptr` which is pretty safe and handy, but OP seems doesn't.

Comment: You recommend poor code. That's unacceptable. And **NO**, it's not because of the design of the OP's project, but because of your choice of using `std::reference_wrapper<>`.

Comment: I think a `reference_wrapper` *may* be an adequate solution in *some* cases. But it should contain a big fat warning: If `collection1` gets altered (as in adding or removing elements) or runs out of scope, any access via `collection2` is undefined behavior and will likely cause a crash.

Comment: @MvG I disagree. There is no conceivable benefit of such a `reference_wrapper` that would outweigh the very real danger of dangling references.

Comment: @Walter: shared pointers come with time and space overhead for reference counting operations. If the lifetime of one collection is clearly a superset of that of the other, such overhead is avoidable, and should be avoided in performance-critical situations. It's a typical performance vs. safety tradeoff, similar to `v[i]` vs. `v.at(i)`. Personally I'd use a collection of pointers, but the difference between pointers and wrapped references is negligible, in my opinion, and for some situations the nicer notation (fewer `*` indirections) may make using the reference wrapper the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: **you cannot fully emulate python in C++**.

Unlike python variables, C++ variables are real objects, not mere references (to objects), the copying of which does nothing to the underlying object and hence is always shallow (moreover, python uses type erasure to allow its variables to reference any possible object).

In C++, this very same design can also be achieved. Since an object must stay alive as long as any reference to it still exists, but be removed (and any memory freed) as soon as the last reference goes out of scope, such objects are *shared*. The C++ way to deal with shared objects is through **`std::shared_ptr<T>`**. See below for the reason why this must be a pointer-like object rather than a reference-like object (such as python variables).

Thus, using C++ in the C++ way, your code would be

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>> collection1, collection2;

collection1.push_back(std::make_shared<Car>("black", "Ford"));
collection1.push_back(std::make_shared<Car>("white", "BMW"));
collection1.push_back(std::make_shared<Car>("yellow", "Audi"));

collection2.push_back(collection1[0]);
collection2[0]->color = "blue";
std::cout<<collection1[0]->color;   // "blue"
```

`std::shared_ptr<T>` behave like pointers, but this is very similar to a reference (which differs from a pointer in its syntax, but is implemented the same).

---

Note that it is **impossible to design in C++ a corresponding `shared_reference<T>`** with the same functionality as python variables, i.e. like `std::shared_ptr<T>` but using `.` instead of `->` and with the guarantee of a valid object (no null/empty reference/pointer). The reason is that the `.` operator cannot be overloaded. For example

```
template<typename T>
struct shared_reference
{
  template<typename...Args>
  shared_reference(Args&&...args)
  : ptr(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
private:
  std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
};
```

then there is way we can make code like

```
shared_reference<car> Car;
Car.color = "blue";
```

work. This is simply how C++ is. It means that for indirection you should use pointers.

Comment: You can go for something like this: `shared_reference<car>.get().color = "blue";` which is a bit clumsy to use, but very straightforward to implement.

Answer (score -2):

Similar but different to what others have said about using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` This maybe of use, but someone has also mentioned this in the comments below your question and that is using smart pointers, the only difference here is that I happen to take it a step farther by creating a template wrapper class. Here is the code and it should do what you are looking for except for this is working on the heap instead of using references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Car {
public:
    std::string color;
    std::string name;
    Car(){}  // Added Default Constructor to be safe.
    Car( std::string colorIn, std::string nameIn ) : color( colorIn ), name( nameIn ){}
};

template<class T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;

    explicit Wrapper( T obj ) {
        ptr = std::make_shared<T>( T( obj ) );
    }

    ~Wrapper() {
        ptr.reset();
    }
};

int main () {

    std::vector<Wrapper<Car>> collection1;
    std::vector<Wrapper<Car>> collection2;

    collection1.emplace_back( Car("black", "Ford") );
    collection1.emplace_back( Car("white", "BMW") );
    collection1.emplace_back( Car("yellow", "Audi") );

    collection2.push_back( collection1[0] );

    std::cout << collection2[0].ptr->color << " " << collection2[0].ptr->name << std::endl;

    collection2[0].ptr->color = std::string( "green" );
    collection2[0].ptr->name  = std::string( "Gremlin" );

    std::cout << collection1[0].ptr->color << " " << collection1[0].ptr->name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you noticed in the code I changed collection 2's first index object's fields and then I printed out collection 1's first index object's fields and they were changed. So what happens in one collection will happen in another because they are `shared memory` by using `std::shared_ptr<T>` the only reason I put it in the wrapper is so that its constructor will make new memory for you upon construction so that you wouldn't have to do this every time; the template wrapper class does this for you and you don't have to worry about cleaning up the memory because `std::shared_ptr<T>'s destructor` should do that for you, but to be safe I did call the `shared_ptr<T>'s release method` in the `Wrapper's destructor`.

To make this a little cleaner or more readable you can do this instead:

```
typedef Wrapper<Car> car;

std::vector<car> collection1;
std::vector<car> collection2;

// rest is same
```

And it will do the same for you.

Now if you don't want to use pointers or the heap you could create another wrapper yourself which would be similar to `std::refrence_wrapper<T>` you can write your own template wrapper for references that is very simple to use. Here is an example:

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper2 {
public:
    T& t;
    explicit Wrapper2( T& obj ) : t(obj) {} 
};
```

Then in your source you would do the same as above and it still works

```
typedef Wrapper2<Car> car2;
std::vector<car2> coll1;
std::vector<car2> coll2;

coll1.emplace_back( Car( "black", "Ford" ) );
coll1.emplace_back( Car( "white", "BMW" ) );
coll1.emplace_back( Car( "yellow", "Audi" ) );

coll2.push_back( coll1[0] );

std::cout << coll2[0].t.color << " " << coll2[0].t.name << std::endl;

coll2[0].t.color = std::string( "brown" );
coll2[0].t.name  = std::string( "Nova" );

std::cout << coll1[0].t.color << " " << coll1[0].t.name << std::endl;
```

And by modifying coll2's first indexed object's fields, coll1's first indexed object's fields are being changed as well.

**EDIT**

@Caleth  asked me this in the comments:

> What benefit is Wrapper over just shared_ptr here? (and Wrapper2 over reference_wrapper)

Without this wrapper look at this code here:

```
class Blob {
public:
    int blah;
    Blob() : blah(0) {}
    explicit Blob( int blahIn ) : blah( blahIn ) {}
};


void someFunc( ... ) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Blob>> blobs;        
    blobs.push_back( std::make_shared<Blob>( Blob( 1 ) ) );
    blobs.push_back( std::make_shared<Blob>( Blob( 2 ) ) );
    blobs.push_back( std::make_shared<Blob>( Blob( 3 ) ) );
}
```

Yeah it is readable but a lot of repetitious typing, now with the wrapper

```
void someFunc( ... ) {   
    typedef Wrapper<Blob> blob;        
    std::vector<blob> blobs;
    blobs.push_back( Blob( 1 ) );
    blobs.push_back( Blob( 2 ) );
    blobs.push_back( Blob( 3 ) );
}
```

Now as for the Wrapper to just a reference; try doing this:

```
void someFunc( ... ) {
    std::vector<int&> ints; // Won't Work     
}
```

However creating a `class template` that stores a `reference` to `obj T` you can now do this:

```
void someFunc( ... ) {
    typedef Wrapper2<Blob> blob;
    std::vector<blob> blobs;

    blobs.push_back( Blob( 1 ) );
    blobs.push_back( Blob( 2 ) );

    // then lets create a second container
    std::vector<blob> blobs2;
    // Push one of the reference objects in container 1 into container two
    blobs2.push_back( blobs[0] );
    // Now blobs2[0] contains the same referenced object as blobs[0]
    // blobs[0].t.blah = 1, blobs[1].t.blah = 2 and blobs2[0].t.blah = 1
    // lets change blobs2[0].t.blah value
    blobs2[0].t.blah = 4;

    // Now blobs1[0].t.blah also = 4.
}
```

You couldn't do this before with references in `std::vector<T>` unless if you used `std::reference_wrapper<T>` which does basically the same thing but much more convoluted. So for simple objects having your own wrappers can come in handy.

**EDIT** - Something that I had overlooked and didn't catch this when working in my IDE because everything compiled, built and ran successfully but it has come to my attention that the OP of this question should completely disregard my second wrapper. This can lead to Undefined Behavior. So you can still use the 1st wrapper of the smart pointer or if you need storable references as others had already pointed out definitely use `std::some_container<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`. I will leave the existing code above for a historical reference for others to learn from. I do thank those involved into pointing out the Undefined Behavior. And for those who don't know please take into consideration that I have no formal training and that I'm 100% self taught and still learning. You can also refer to this question that I had asked concerning references and undefined behavior here: [undefined behavior of references on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483552/will-creating-a-class-template-wrapper-of-a-reference-cause-undefined-behavoir#41483903)

**Conclusion**

Trying to use references of the same objects in multiple containers can be a bad idea because it can lead to **Undefined Behavior** when something is added or removed from either container leaving dangling references. So the proper or safer choice would be to use `std::shared_ptr<T>` to achieve the functionality that you want.

There is nothing wrong with using references but special care and design does need to be taken into consideration especially about the lifetime of the objects that are being referenced. If the objects are moved and then the reference is being accessed afterwards this will lead to problems, but if you know the lifetime of the object and that it will not be moved or destroyed, then accessing the references is not a problem. I'd still suggest using `std::shared_ptr` or `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: What benefit is Wrapper over just shared_ptr here? (and Wrapper2 over reference_wrapper)

Comment: @Caleth There isn't a much of one, but the one benefit of the `shared_ptr` wrapper is that its constructor automatically calls `std::make_shared<T>` for you. This way if you do have a `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` you wouldn't have to call `make_shared<T>` every time you want to push something into that vector, the wrapper class does this for you. As for the reference it does what it is supposed to. You can not have a `vector<class &T>` but with this wrapper, similar to `std::reference_wrapper<T>` as you can see when you have multiple containers of the same object, changing one changes the other.

Comment: @Caleth ... basically the wrapper around the `shared_ptr<T>` is a template so when you pass in any class T it automatically makes that class object a `shared_ptr<T>` by calling `std::make_shared<T>` in its constructor. And it's destructor calls its `reset()` method.

Comment: Ok, having looked up shared_ptr constructors, I see it is useful, but I would have `template <typename ... Args>Wrapper::Wrapper(Args ... args){ ptr = make_shared(std::forward(args...)) }`. I still don't get why you are re-implementing reference_wrapper

Comment: @Caleth check out the answer I edited it put an example there at the end.

Comment: In your second example, you have dangling references. You are constructing temporary blobs

Comment: @Caleth ... I'm not saying you are wrong; but I'm just trying to see it... I'm 100% self taught with no formal training or classes. Been working with C++ since around 2003.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132376/discussion-between-francis-cugler-and-caleth).

Comment: Your answer is too long and muddled (it's several answers in one). Your `Wrapper2` is horrible design and prone to dangling references. A C++ programmer should never even contemplate such design.

Comment: @Walter I overlooked the fact of UB when working in my IDE for it did compile, build and gave valid results. It was already brought to my attention and I did leave an edit at the bottom of the page. I could of deleted it all, but left it for historical purposes and mentioned it at the end.

Comment: @Walter and FYI I'm 100% self taught, no formal training or any classes of any type I do know the language fairly well and I do understand the compiler to a certain degree, but I'm still learning. I've never had any one teach me the language.

Comment: @FrancisCugler neither had I.