# Will creating a class template wrapper of a reference cause undefined behavoir?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, wrapper, undefined-behavior

Here is a code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    T& t;
    explicit Wrapper2( T& obj ) : t(obj) {} 
};

class Car {
public:
    std::string color;
    std::string name;
    Car(){}
    Car( std::string colorIn, std::string nameIn ) : color( colorIn ), name( nameIn ){}
};

int _tmain( int iNumArguments, _TCHAR* pArgumentText[] ) {
    typedef Wrapper<Car> car;

    // Create 2 Containers
    std::vector<car> collection1;
    std::vector<car> collection2;

    // Populate collection 1 with reference objects
    collection1.push_back( Car("black", "Ford") );
    collection1.push_back( Car("white", "BMW") );
    collection1.push_back( Car("yellow", "Audi") );

    // use referenced object at index 0 in collection 1
    // to populate index 0 of collection 2
    collection2.push_back( collection1[0] );

    // Print Out index 0 of collection2's referenced object's fields
    std::cout << collection2[0].t.color << " " << collection2[0].t.name << std::endl;

    // Change collection2's index 0 referenced object's fields
    collection2[0].t.color = std::string( "green" );
    collection2[0].t.name  = std::string( "Gremlin" );

    // Print out collection1's index 0 referenced object's fields
    // and they are changed
    std::cout << collection1[0].ptr->color << " " << collection1[0].ptr->name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This does compile, build and run successfully in MSVS2015 CE without any errors.

Does this or can this generate Undefined Behavior and if so; How?

Comment: You probably want [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I know about `std::reference_wrapper` I just wanted to know if this would allow for undefined behavior.

Comment: You're bathing in UB because you're storing references to temporaries and using them later.

Comment: @Quentin Okay just wanted some verification. So in essence this can work as it did in this case, but depending on other circumstances, it is left up to the compiler to shred this apart and isn't reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. So basically this would work as long as it remains in the same scope, but once you go out of that scope into a different stack frame; this would break down then.

Comment: The other compilers really dont like this code. That says a lot.

Comment: @FrancisCugler there are no guarantees that it would work within the same scope, nor that it will stop working out of scope. But that's one possible outcome of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PaulRooney That is funny and ironic because I don't have any other compiler only MSVS2015 CE

Answer (score 2):

> Will creating a class template wrapper of a reference cause undefined behavoir?

No.

However misusing references (and pointers and iterators) in general does. If the referenced object is destroyed, that reference is left dangling. This happens to all references, not only those wrapped in a class - the wrapper has no effect. When the reference dangles, using it has undefined behaviour.

> ```
> collection1.push_back( Car("black", "Ford") );
> ```

Here, The object is a temporary. The object exists until the end of `push_back`. After that the reference in the wrapper in the vector is dangling.

> ```
> std::cout << collection2[0].t.color << " " << collection2[0].t.name << std::endl;
> ```

Here you use a dangling reference and the program has undefined behaviour.

---

Here is an example of using the wrapper that has no UB:

```
Car c;
collection1.push_back(c);
collection1[0].color = "black";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer; this came about when answer a question on another post and they wanted to store objects into `std::vector` having multiple containers where if they modify say `vector2[0]` then `vector1[0]` would be modified as well similar to how some functionality of `python` works. Some suggested to them `std::reference_wrapper` and others `shared_ptr`. I was trying to show them a simple custom class template wrapper that would wrap either `shared_ptr` or `reference`.

Comment: @FrancisCugler your wrapper is a limited version of `std::reference_wrapper`. A reference wrapper works fine, if you have one "master" container that contains the objects themselves (not references) that is *never* modified, and other containers have references to the master. With the shared_ptr alternative, all containers are equal, and may be modified freely.

Comment: I asked a follow up question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485042/dangling-references-leading-to-undefined-behavoir