# Dangling References leading to undefined behavior

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior

I had asked a previous question about references and undefined behavior here: [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41483552/72178) and based on the answer given and some of the comments such as the comment by user2079303 where they stated this:

> A reference wrapper works fine, if you have one "master" container that contains the objects themselves (not references) that is never modified, and other containers have references to the master

My new question becomes this: Will this help alleviate the possibility of dangling references that can lead to undefined behavior?

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper {
private:
    T object;
public:
    T& referenced_object;
    explicit Wrapper( T& obj ) : object(obj), referenced_object( object ) {}
};
```

It would be used in the same manner as seen in the previous question where multiple containers would hold the same referenced objects where if one object is modified in one container, the corresponding reference of that object will also be modified in the other container.

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the purpose of the wrapper by including a copy? If you look at `std::reference_wrapper` it disallows creation from temporary objects, thus meaning it has to be created from something that already exists. As long as you understand the lifetime of the referenced object its a valid thing to do.

Comment: @PaulRooney hmm I had given the wrapper in the previous question as an answer to another question and others were saying it was bad design, that it will lead to dangling references and thus undefined behavior. So I then asked the previous question and with the response from user2079303 it lead me to this. I was thinking on the lines of having a valid object as private, but only being able to have a reference accessible to it, then again your comment does make sense about it defeating the purpose. I do know about `std::reference_wrapper` but was trying to make a very simple one.

Comment: It all depends on how you design your code.  If the thing that takes a reference or a non owning pointer to something outlives that something then you have a problem.  If you are passing them to a function however that is OK since the variable has to be alive while the function runs(not considering threads).  You really need to sit down and look at the design and make sure you do not have cases where the object being referred to does not outlive the reference.

Comment: Thank you for the comments; I was thinking on similar lines as these comments but started to second guess myself when others were putting down a previous answer of mine.

Answer (score 2):

Such wrapper makes no sense, if you store the copy itself then there's no need for reference. And your reference becomes invalid when you move this object (eg. when it's being stored in `std::vector` and it reallocates memory).

References and `std::reference_wrapper` work just fine, but don't move your object. Keeping objects in `std::list` guarantees that they won't be moved, so you can use it and point references in multiple containers to its objects.

Comment: Okay thank you; just wanted to clarify this, I was initially thinking this, but then started to second guess myself.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this help alleviate the possibility of dangling references that can lead to undefined behavior?

It would... but each instance of this wrapper will hold their own object, and so it therefore won't achieve your original goal of "multiple containers would hold the same referenced objects"

Also, the implicit copy/move constructor/assignment will copy/move the internal object, but the copy of the reference will refer to the original object instead of the copy - which again leads to possibility of dangling references.

The reference of this wrapper appears to serve no purpose.